# cannot find/kill (node) http-server process which is in infinite loop on macOS

Tags: node.js, macos, infinite-loop, httpserver, npx

i was running a local http server using the command:
`./node_modules/.bin/http-server -a localhost dist`

i think the code contained an infinite loop and since then, i cannot kill nor find the process.

i exited the process in the terminal, even restarted the computer (macOS 13.4).

checking `lsof -i :8080` or `lsof -i -P | grep 8080` shows nothing.

but when i open localhost:8080 in Chrome, the app opens and is running in an infinite loop.

where is this process?

Comment: No if you restarted your machine, the server process is definitively not running anymore unless you explicitly configured it as a service. If you can still see it in chrome, it's probably just in the browser's cache

Answer (score 1):

If you restarted your Mac, or you have killed the process, using one of the following commands

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)
```

or more brutal

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080)
```

you won't see it as a running process.

To eliminate the possibility that you in fact see Chrome's cache, please try

`localhost:8080`

in Private mode or some other browser instead.

Comment: It's possible to create a launch daemon or launch agent item to auto-restart processes after it exits or the system is restarted (see ["how to kill process in Mac OS X and not have it restart on its own"](https://superuser.com/questions/159486/how-to-kill-process-in-mac-os-x-and-not-have-it-restart-on-its-own) for example). I don't see any indication that OP did that, so the browser cache seems like the most likely suspect.